# Link to a different page within an included file, to be loaded on the same parent file

Tags: php, html, ajax

I hope this question makes sense because it seems simple, yet I can't work out exactly how to word it in an understandable way.

Basically - I have an Ajax system for loading content onto an HTML file via a seperate PHP file. This is to not need the actual page the browser has loaded to change, only the content.

What I would like to do it be able to create a link WITHIN one of the loaded content pages, which will change the content to another page via the parent. For example:

1. Load the 'menu' page using Ajax, onto a div contained in the main page
2. Click a link on the 'menu' page, and a different page is loaded onto the same div on the main page

Cheers

Comment: I have only tried the same method that is used on the 'main page', which is basically a line similar to this: <a class="MenuCircles" id="menuItem1">SERVICES</a>. The class is what the Ajax script looks for, and the 'id' tells it which page to load. Within the page (say menuItem1) however, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Create a javascript function to load content, and then create javascript: links, or onclick handlers to run it with the requested page :)

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail :) Java loads the content as explained in the comment I left on the main question, I just don't know how to use this within a loaded page